# Attempting to store the return array of Object.keys(obj) in an array using javascript, but getting the error "ReferenceError: array is not defined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What is wrong with this code?
I don't understand why this line "arrKeys = Object.keys(source);" isn't returning the array as its supposed to do.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) { 
var arr = [];                    // should return the array of properties and values found in the array object
var arrkeys = [];
arrKeys = Object.keys(source);   // should return ["last"] 
var test = false;
// Loops through the collections array object and searches for the object that matches the second argument passed to the method
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){    
for(var j = 0; j < arrKeys.length; j++){
  if(collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arrKeys[j])){
      if(collection[i][arrKeys[j]] ===  source[arrKeys[j]]){
        test = true;
      }else{
          break;
      }
  } else{
      break;
   }
    if(j === (arrkeys.length - 1) && test === true){
      arr.push(collection[i]);
      } 
    }// end of inner for loop   
  }// end of inner for loop
 return arr; 
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio",   last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos

```
var arrKeys = [];
//     ^

if(j === (arrKeys.length - 1) && test === true){
//           ^
```

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var arr = [];                    // should return the array of properties and values found in the array object
    var arrKeys = Object.keys(source);   // should return ["last"] 
    var test = false;
    // Loops through the collections array object and searches for the object that matches the second argument passed to the method
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arrKeys.length; j++) {
            if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arrKeys[j])) {
                if (collection[i][arrKeys[j]] === source[arrKeys[j]]) {
                    test = true;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
            if (j === (arrKeys.length - 1) && test === true) {
                arr.push(collection[i]);
            }
        }// end of inner for loop   
    }// end of inner for loop
    return arr;
}


console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }));
```